# Passing nullable guid to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

When I pass nullable guid parameter to stored procedure in my c# code below. I am getting exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near
>   '@customerGuid'.

```
var userNameSqlParam = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "userName",
    Value = userName,
    DbType = DbType.String
};

var customerGuidSqlParam = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "customerGuid",
    Value = customerGuid,
    DbType = DbType.Guid
};

var rows = _dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<CurrentUserContextWithoutCustomer>
        ("EXEC [dbo].[GetCurrentUserContext] @userName @customerGuid",
        userNameSqlParam, customerGuidSqlParam)
    .ToList();
```

So when I look by SQL Profiler what was called I get

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'EXEC [dbo].[GetCurrentUserContext] @userName @customerGuid',
N'@userName nvarchar(4),@customerGuid uniqueidentifier',
@userName=N'gir1',@customerGuid=default
```

I see **default** on the end of query. It generates problem.
There is header of stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrentUserContext]
    @userName nvarchar(100),
    @customerGuid uniqueidentifier
AS
```

How can I pass nullable guid to sql as stored procedure parameter.

Comment: No, just a moment

Comment: You should comma separate parameters in an `EXEC` statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all you should send a `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`

```
var customerGuidSqlParam = new SqlParameter
{
    ParameterName = "customerGuid",
    Value = (object)customerGuid ?? (object)DBNull.Value,
    DbType = DbType.Guid
};
```

and you have missed a comma in your query.

```
var rows = _dbContext.Database
    .SqlQuery<CurrentUserContextWithoutCustomer>
        ("EXEC [dbo].[GetCurrentUserContext] @userName, @customerGuid",
        userNameSqlParam, customerGuidSqlParam)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

In your stored procedure set the default value to null

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetCurrentUserContext]
    @userName nvarchar(100),
    @customerGuid uniqueidentifier = NULL
AS
```

Comment: It not works in case when I pass two params, Default NULL will be overrided by "default" value from passing param.
Of course I can call procedure with one param when customerGuid is null, but I prefer to avoid if-ing.

Comment: @Jacek - have you tried it? If you execute the procedure MidTwo has supplied as `exec GetCurrentUserContext @userName='abc', @customerGuid = default` then inside the procedure, `@userName` is `abc` and `@customerGuid` is `NULL`. If you want to use the *default*, you have to tell SQL Server what the default *should be*, and you do that by supplying the default after an `=` in the procedure's parameter list, as shown here.

Answer (score 2):

you can put this in your C# end

```
Value = customerGuid == null ? (object)DBNull.Value : customerGuid.Value
```

and at stored procedure end as suggested from the earlier answer:

> @customerGuid uniqueidentifier = NULL

When there is null, it will pass null. if there is value you will get it in @customerGuid param.